# Split job into two threads, with use wait, waitpid, fork

Tags: c, fork, wait, waitpid

I want split job into two child process. One child find min value, and another max value. 
Here is sample code:

http://pastebin.com/P29wsRdP

Now return value is min:0 max:0, could you look at this?

Answer (score 1):

The processes do not share memory. The min/maxvalue global variables modified by the functions are local to the process. None of them will touch the parent min/maxvalue variables.
You need to communicate the results in some way, e.g. using pipe/sockets.

I think you have a further problem you are spawning three processes actually.
the first process forked with the first fork() will execute the second fork() because this is not guarded by an if.

Comment: But is any chance to not using pipie/sockets, only catch return data from each process?

Comment: No other way that I would be proud of having proposed.

Comment: Macro: int WEXITSTATUS (int status)
If WIFEXITED is true of status, this macro returns the low-order 8 bits of the exit status value from the child process. See section Exit Status (this means is not going to work for an int, only for values below 256). Furthermore, the exit status should be 0 on processes that terminates with success and should not be used arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

You are not splitting into threads, you are splitting into new processes, each with their own version of the variables (as both new processes have their own independent memory). You either need some sort of IPC, or you need to actually use threads.

Comment: Ok, change to static int minValue=0; but dont affect. Maybe how catch return value, each process?

Comment: you're not getting this; the forked processes' *each have their own copy of the variable* which means that when they operate on *their copy*, the original value *in the parent*, which is what you are printing out, is never changed. You really need to read up on the difference between a forked process and a thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using threads as others have described.

But why are you doing this when you can both look for the min/max in just the one loop?

Comment: Y're thinking its the point search min/max value?? And i try do something with fork() to do that? Pls...

Comment: Just looking at the supplied code. One look could find both the min/max.